# Using GridBagLayout to set multiple components in one panel, but I dont want to fill up the whole panel

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel, gridbaglayout

I'm working on a project where I'm building a GUI using java swing. At the moment I have one `Jpanel` in a `JFrame` that should contain a label (question) and a set of buttons/textfield (answers), which can change based on the question that is being asked. I want to have the question centered somewhere at the top, with the answers being appropiately centered in the middle. At the moment I use `GridBagLayout` to set the `JLabel` and `JButton`s but still no succes.

```
public class QuestionPanel extends MoviePanel{

    private String question;

    public QuestionPanel(String type, Application app, String question) throws Exception{
        super(type, app);
        this.question = question;
        JLabel lab = new JLabel(this.question);

        this.getGbc().anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        this.getGbc().fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        this.getGbc().weighty = 0.5;
        this.getGbc().gridx = 2;
        this.getGbc().gridy = 0;

        lab.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 40));
        lab.setForeground(new Color(189, 189, 189, 255));
        add(lab, this.getGbc());

        getAnswers(type);
    }

    private void getAnswers(String type){
        if(type.equals("AgeRestriction")){
            this.getGbc().gridx=0;
            this.getGbc().gridy=1;
            add(new YesButton(this.getApp()),this.getGbc());

            this.getGbc().gridx = 3;
            this.getGbc().gridy = 1;
            add(new NoButton(this.getApp()),this.getGbc());
        }
    }
}
```

The `GridBagLayout` is being set in `super MoviePanel` and `this.getGbc()` returns the appropiate `GridBagConstraints`. At the moment the layout I have looks like this:

[image: layout]

The idea is to have the yes and no button close to each other and future buttons to be dynamically located in the center.

## Solution

I ended up solving by combining the answers of [angushjoshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12320142/angusjoshi) and [c0der](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3992939/c0der), so adding an answerPanel in the questionPanel with GridBagLayout. My code now looks like this:

```
public class QuestionPanel extends MoviePanel {

    private String question;
    private JPanel answerPanel = new JPanel();

    public QuestionPanel(String type, Application app, String question) throws Exception {
        super(type, app);
        this.question = question;
        JLabel lab = new JLabel(this.question);
        answerPanel.setOpaque(false);


        this.getGbc().anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        this.getGbc().weighty = 1;
        this.getGbc().gridy = 0;
        this.getGbc().gridx = 2;
        this.getGbc().gridwidth = 3;

        lab.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 40));
        lab.setForeground(new Color(189, 189, 189, 255));
        add(lab, this.getGbc());

        getAnswers(type);
    }

    public void getAnswers(String type) {
        if (type.equals("AgeRestriction")) {
            createYesNoButtons();
        }
        if (type.equals("Age")) {
            createAgeField();
        }
        if (type.equals("Genre")){
            createGenreButtons();
        }
        if (type.equals("Actor")){
            createActorField();
        }
    }


    private void createYesNoButtons() {
        this.getGbc().weighty = 0.5;
        this.getGbc().anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
       answerPanel.add(new YesButton(this.getApp()));
       answerPanel.add(new NoButton(this.getApp()));
       this.add(answerPanel,this.getGbc());
    }

    private void createAgeField() {
        this.getGbc().weighty = 0.5;
        this.getGbc().anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        answerPanel.add(new AgeField(this.getApp()));
        this.add(answerPanel,this.getGbc());
    }

    private void createGenreButtons(){
    }

    private void createActorField(){
    }

}
```

And now the panel looks like this:

[image: layout]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please explain _"future buttons to be dynamically located in the center."_  do you mean other buttons ? or additional buttons ?  Please post [mre]

Comment: What I meant was that when I have a different multiple choice question that has a different number of options the options would be displayed evenly along the x-axis. For instance like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbJD2.png

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to code that atm. I guess you could could count the possible options and iterate through them placing them one at a time. Just updating the gridx as you go through them. But yeah that's something I can figure out later. But that's what I meant with it.

Comment: *and a set of buttons/textfield (answers), which can change based on the question that is being asked.* - maybe use a `CardLayout` so you can swap in a whole panel based on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend breaking the layout into smaller, easier to layout parts. 
In this case use 3 `JPanel`s and demonstrated by the following [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class QuestionAnswerPanel extends JPanel{

    private Image background;
    //use publicly available resources when posting questions or answers
    private final String imageLink = "https://www.whatsonnetwork.co.uk/uploads/800x600/98331337cb0f7f31c874e22a8f2b5f8b.jpg";

    QuestionAnswerPanel() {

        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(imageLink);
            background = ImageIO.read(url);
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(background.getWidth(null), background.getHeight(null)));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        //border layout  allows you to add components to 5 positions,
        //including north and center
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //have a JPanel for the question
        JLabel lab = new JLabel("To Be Or Not To Be ?");
        lab.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 40));
        lab.setForeground(new Color(189, 189, 189, 255));
        JPanel questionPanel = new JPanel();
        questionPanel.setOpaque(false);
        questionPanel.add(lab);
        add(questionPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH); //place it at the top

        //have a JPanel for the answer
        JPanel answerPanel = new JPanel();
        answerPanel.setOpaque(false);
        //use GridBagLayout to center components
        answerPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        //add components as you need
        answerPanel.add(new JButton("Yes"));
        answerPanel.add(new JButton("No"));
        add(answerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);//place it at the center
    }


    @Override //Override to paint image at the background
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new QuestionAnswerPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: True, that's of course always an option, thanks! But I am kind of set on solving this by using only one panel.

Comment: @lukaf, *But I am kind of set on solving this by using only one panel.* - wrong approach. You should be using the appropriate tool for the job. It is better to break down the UI logically and use the appropriate layout managers. If will allow for easier development and maintenance in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give you an exact solution to your problem, but I can tell you that you might want to play with `GridBagConstraints.insets` and `GridBagConstraints.anchor`.

`insets` is used to change the padding around an object in your layout i.e. the minimum distance from the edge of the JPanel. You might use it like this:

`this.getGbc().insets = new Inset(top,right,bottom,left);`

`anchor` is used to say where you want your object to be placed in the layout, for example:
`this.getGbc().anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;`

Here's some useful `GridBagConstraints.anchor` values:

FIRST_LINE_START      ...   PAGE_START       ...    FIRST_LINE_END

LINE_START            ...     CENTER             ...    LINE_END

LAST_LINE_START  ...   PAGE_END ... LAST_LINE_END